# merging 3 dataframes with different indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 3 DFs: GDP, energy, ScimEn.

```
print(GDP.index.name) > Country
print(energy.index.name) > None
print(ScimEn.index.name) > None
```

Although energy and ScimEn do have a 'Country' column.
I would like to merge all DFs on 'Country'. How can I do that? I have tried to do the following

```
newdf = (pd.merge(energy, ScimEn, how='inner', on='Country').merge(GDP, how='inner', on=GDP.index.name))
> KeyError: 'Country'
```

If I try:

```
newdf = (pd.merge(energy, ScimEn, how='inner', on='Country').
         merge(GDP, how='inner', left_index=True))
    raise MergeError('Must pass right_on or right_index=True')
pandas.tools.merge.MergeError: Must pass right_on or right_index=True
```

If I try:

```
newdf = (pd.merge(energy, ScimEn, how='inner', on='Country').
         merge(GDP, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

It returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Country, Energy Supply, Energy Supply per Capita, % Renewable, Rank, Documents, Citable documents, Citations, Self-citations, Citations per document, H index, Country Code, Indicator Name, Indicator Code, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]
Index: []
```

Comment: maybe need change `on=GDP.index.name` to `left_index=True`

Comment: I posted results to my original post

Comment: Thanks, what about `newdf = (pd.merge(energy, ScimEn, on='Country').merge(GDP.reset_index(), on='Country'))` ?

Comment: awesome. it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to `GDP`:

```
newdf = pd.merge(energy.reset_index(), ScimEn, on='Country').merge(GDP.reset_index(), on='Country')
```

Alternative if many `DataFrames`:

```
from  functools import reduce
dfs = [energy.reset_index(), ScimEn, GDP.reset_index()]
newdf = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Country'), dfs)
```

Solution without `reset_index` with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
newdf = pd.merge(energy.reset_index(), ScimEn, on='Country').join(GDP, on='Country', how='inner')
```

Comment: Yes, sure. Check it.